# xtraGrid NewRow and Entity Framework

Tags: entity, xtragrid

```
orderBindingSource.DataSource = _orderEntity;
orderLineBindingSource.DataSource = _orderEntity.OrderLines;
xtraGridOrderLine.DataSource = orderLineBindingSource;
```

How to achieve the following tasks?

1/ When a user begins typing on the NewRow, an  entity should be added to _orderEntity.OrderLines.

2/ When a user cancels the NewRow, the inserted  entity should be removed from _orderEntity.OrderLines.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
        void viewOrderLine_InitNewRow(object sender, InitNewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = (OrderLine)viewOrderLine.GetRow(viewOrderLine.FocusedRowHandle);
        row.Order = _orderEntity;
        _orderEntity.OrderLines.Add(row);
        viewOrderLine.FocusedColumn = viewOrderLine.VisibleColumns[0];
    }
```